# Great circle rendering of satellite ground tracks reversed in southern hemisphere

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, geoserver, openlayers, great-circle

I'm working on rendering some satellite ground tracks from postgis, through geoserver, and onto openlayers. The python library I'm using to get lat, lon from TLE data isn't perfect, so there are distortions in the lines.

[image: RawData]

To smooth the lines out, I wanted to use the great circle projection solution that I've used before. https://anitagraser.com/2011/08/20/visualizing-global-connections/

Unfortunately, the great circle lines drawn in the southern hemisphere are being projected in the wrong direction(I think). Is the 953027 projection only valid in the northern hemisphere?

[image]

The data is currently stored as a multilinestring in the DB, and the reprojection is being done by geoserver in a view.

Any ideas on how I can correct the great circle projection in the southern hemisphere?

EDIT: Here's some additional info if it helps.

The multilinestrings I'm working with are comprised of 180(one per minute for 3 hrs) points. The density of the points can be adjusted fairly easily, just takes a bit to run the script. They span from -180 to 180 and are split into multi to avoid the wrapping issue. This is an example if you want to look at one. https://pastebin.com/nfmRDkwm

My transform :

```
select  ST_Transform(ST_Segmentize(ST_Transform(ST_Force2D(sat_lines::geometry), 953027), 100000), 4326) as sat_lines LIMIT 5
```

953027 Projection

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 953027, 'esri', 53027, '+proj=eqdc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +lat_1=60 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs ', 'PROJCS["Sphere_Equidistant_Conic",GEOGCS["GCS_Sphere",DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_Authalic_Sphere",SPHEROID["Sphere",6371000,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Equidistant_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",60],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",60],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0],UNIT["Meter",1],AUTHORITY["EPSG","53027"]]');
```

Comment: Should include more information here in the question like the definition of 953027 (no, it's valid in both hemispheres but it's conic, designed for northern hemisphere so maybe the data isn't dense enough in the south). You should also post at least some of the code of the densification algorithm.

Comment: @mkennedy Thanks for the reply. I updated the post with some more information. Unless the ST_Segmentize counts as a densification algorithm, I'm not using one. I believe all the relevant information is in the post now. If 953027 is conic for the northern hemisphere, is there corresponding projection for the southern hemisphere that I should be using?

Comment: Based on this, https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1019, it looks like ST_Segmentize is a densification algorithm.

Comment: Try changing the definition to [+eqc](http://proj4.org/projections/eqc.html), drop lat_1 and lat_2 and add +lat_ts=60. That will switch it to equidistant cylindrical with standard parallels at +/-60. It that works better, then it was a densification problem.

Comment: @mkennedy I changed the proj4text to "+proj=eqc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs", but now it looks just like it did before I did the transform-segmentize-transform. Do I need to change the srtext as well to reflect the changes?

Comment: I adjusted the srtext to match the changes in proj4text, but that didn't seem to have any effect.